# U-sql error json

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to extract data from the Data Lake store, which are saved in the json. When I try to submit script I get the error:

> Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed:
>   SV1_Extract[0] with error: Vertex user code error.

I will add that I used:
https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [jsonextr];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
@searchlog =
    EXTRACT city string
    FROM "/weather/logs/2016/09/23/08_0_a26cf4d21dd24f53b7903a9206195c58.json"
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@res =
    SELECT *
    FROM @searchlog;        

OUTPUT @res   
    TO "/datastreamanalitics/SearchLog-from-Data-Lake.json"
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonOutputter();
```

json:

```
{"city":{"id":7532702,"name":"Brodnica","coord":{"lon":19.406401,"lat":53.2579},"country":"PL","population":0},"cod":"200","message":0.0067,"cnt":1,"list":[{"dt":1474624800,"temp":{"day":15.97,"min":10,"max":17.14,"night":10.01,"eve":17.02,"morn":10},"pressure":1025.32,"humidity":79,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"speed":3.22,"deg":271,"clouds":32}],"EventProcessedUtcTime":"2016-09-23T08:04:06.9372695Z","PartitionId":0,"EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2016-09-23T08:04:05.2300000Z"}
```

Comment: Can I add something to JsonExtract?

Comment: I tried to repro your problem but the sample you provided and the script works without a problem. Do you have a sample that fails? Also, these "vertex failed fast" messages are useless. Can you please provide the inner error that you are getting?